# How does a shear layer make vortices?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, vortex

How does a shear layer make vortices? If you have 2 streams of air that are moving at different speeds or opposite directions right beside each other, how does that make a vortex? What causes the rotation, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

The shear layer is already rotational: The vorticity ${\boldsymbol \omega}=\nabla \times {\bf v}\ne 0$.   The individial vortices assemble  from the continuously distributed  vorticity   because of the [Kelvin Helmholtz instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_instability).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question : How is the shear layer already rotational? If the streams are going exactly opposite directions beside each other, where is the rotation?

Comment: For flow in the $x$ direction, the  $z$ component of vorticity is $\omega_z =-\partial_y v_x$. The angular velocity of each  small volume of fluid is $\omega_z/2$, and this means that there is an angular momentum density. This is explained in any fluid mechanics book. The factor of  1/2 is annoying, but is traditional definition of vorticity.

Comment: ah okay. I'm assuming the source of the vortex component has something to do with the fluid instability? Sorry if I'm not picking up on something.

Comment: It's just that if something has its top and bottom parts moving at different velocities, then it has some rotational motion. A shear flow is precisely a fluid that has such different velocities.

Answer (score 0):

Think of spinning a suspended bicycle wheel by quickly moving your hand across the top of it